# Запуск стандартной активности влияет на дальнейшую компановку

Tags: java, android, imageview, камера

У меня есть два способа получения изображений, из галереи (1) и с камеры (2). После получения строки содержащей путь к изображению (для обоих случаев - imagePath), запускаю общую для обоих способов функцию вызова следующей активности в которой это изображение используется (3).

По коду проблем нету, читайте дальше.

1. Получение изображения из галереи

   ```
   Intent galleryPictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
   galleryPictureIntent.setType("image/*");
   startActivityForResult(galleryPictureIntent, GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST);
   ```
2. Получение изображения с камеры

   ```
   Intent cameraPictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   cameraPictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
   startActivityForResult(cameraPictureIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
   ```
3. Обработка результатов

   ```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
   {
       if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
       {
           File cameraImage = new File(imagePath);
           if (cameraImage.length() == 0)
               return;
       }
       else if (requestCode == GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST && data != null)
       {
           Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
           imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(this, selectedImage);
       }

       callPictureActivity();
   }

   private void callPictureActivity()
   {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, PictureWorkActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("picturePath", imagePath);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```

И всё бы хорошо. НО когда я вызываю `callPictureActivity()` после получения изображения с камеры, в вызванной активности наблюдается ненормальное поведение, которое отличается от того что происходит просто при вызове `callPictureActivity()`. Подробности излишни, но для интересующихся `ImageView` в которое попадает изображение немножко съезжает от центра экрана.

Что я пробовал и понял:
При выборе того же изображения из галереи - всё проходит штатно.
Если убрать вызов `callPictureActivity()` из `onActivityResult()` и вызвать вручную(по кнопке) после вызова камеры - всё проходит штатно.
Не важно какое изображение содержится в `imagePath`.
Если активность со съехавшим imageView перезапустить (наклонить экран туда-сюда) `ImageView` становится на место.

Выводы:
Каким-то непостижимым образом вызов стандартной активности с камерой влияет на компоновку другой вызванной активности. Видимо при вызове `onActivityResult()` активность с камерой еще сохраняется или я не знаю...

По просьбе добавляю layout в котором съезжает `ImageView`.
Я использую layout с `Toolbar`'ом в рабочую область которого вставлен данный layout, но если используемый заменить этим, то баг точно также повторяется.
`ImageView` добавляется в ui_mainLayout функцией `addView()`. Но проблема не тут, разность поведения возникает именно из-за активности камеры.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ui_commonLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/ui_mainLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      tools:context=".PictureWorkActivity">

  </FrameLayout>

  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/ui_progressImageLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      tools:context=".PictureWorkActivity">

  </FrameLayout>

  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/ui_completeImageLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      tools:context=".PictureWorkActivity">

  </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: И все таки мне кажется что проблема в `ImageView`, попробуйте ее в xml создать, а в коде лишь фото ставить через `setImageBitmap`

Comment: А почему у вас в `onActivityResult` переменная `imagePath` инициализируется в `else` для галереи, а в `if` для камеры непонятно что написано?

Comment: А вы удаляете старую`ImageView` перед добавлением новой?

Comment: imagePath глобальная переменная, для камеры она инициализируется перед вызовом активности при создании файла который кладется в MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT.

Comment: Если использовать setImageBitmap() то изображение добавляется по центру, как и должно быть. Но проблема всё еще не решена, потому что мне необходимо рисовать поверх изображения, и координаты по прежнему почему-то смещены. Но думаю я уже близок к решению.

Comment: Проблема локализовалась до выдачи неправильного значения (1876 вместо 1810) функцией getHeight() у ImageView при запуске новой активности после камеры.

Comment: в след. раз кидайте весь код, относящийся к проблеме :)

Comment: Итак, грамотно устранить баг не получилось. Пришлось поставить костыли в виде сохранения значения высоты ImageView и последующего пересчета необходимых координат при отличии текущей высоты от сохраненной. Как показали эксперементы метод OnDraw() у ImageView вызывается 2 раза с неправильной высотой (больше на 66), на третий раз высота меняется на нормальную. Так происходит только после вызова активности с ImageView после стандартной активности камеры в методе onActivityResult(). Проблема решена, Flippy - спасибо за участие.